# Getting past the second stage of the gauntlet

Tags: mortal-kombat-11

So I've moved past the tutorial stage on the main gauntlet in the towers of time and now am on the second level with Cassie and Jackie. I've done plenty of other towers in the meantime thinking my skills may increase just enough, but this is too hard man. What konsumable/character did you all end up using to actually beat it?

Answer (score 2):

To anybody who reads this, I just set my AI fighter through it a number of times and they eventually got it. I did find that it was easier to do with a kung lao AI at 30 Rushdown and 30 kombos though, if that helps any.